# Ruby on Rails ApplicationController RESTful actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a nice DRY way to refactor my controllers? all my controllers look exactly the same just change the model name, for example

```
class ModelnamesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @modelnames = Modelname.find(:all)
   end

   def new
      @modelname = Modelname.new
   end
   ...
end
```

And so on for the 7 default REST actions (index, new, create, update, destroy, edit, update), all my controllers just change the model name, so, is there a way to put that code on the `ApplicationController` so my ModelnamesController and every other model controller just extend from `ApplicationController` and if I need to make an action different just overwrite that action?, I'm hoping that my controllers look like this:

```
class ModelnamesController < ApplicationController
end
```

Comment: Try Modelname.All instead of find(:all)

Comment: @SamD What I want to know is if there's a way to put the actions in the applicationcontroller and that they work for every model

Comment: Its the goal of https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources used behind the scene by cancan

Comment: thanks @apneadiving that's what I was looking for, if you put it as an answer I'd be happy to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) which does it out of the box and is used behind the scene by gems like Cancan and activeAdmin.

Answer (score -1):

You are essentially asking the ApplicationController to not only be the master controller but to handle information routing (application level routing) as well. That breaks the intention of the MVC pattern, since the pattern is applied per Entity. It decouples the technology from the business (whatever you are writing the app for) such that maintenance and extensibility will probably be complete nightmares through the life of the application. It is redundant on the way that routing works in RoR applications, since routing (and the implementation of MVC) works on naming conventions that are intended to provide a sufficient, but not burdensome, coupling between the solution and the business.

You don't want Ruby or Rails, you want the Pi Calculus.